# Visual Studio command to wrap selection in parenthesis

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

Does anyone know of a way in Visual Studio 2013 to wrap a selection in parenthesis?  It sounds like something that could be built in but I can't figure it out.  I also use Resharper 9.1.1 if that has a similar feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ReSharper's ["surround with"](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/help/Templates__Applying_Templates__Surrounding_Code_Fragments_with_Templates.html) functionality. Select the code, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>U</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> if you use the IntelliJ shortcut scheme).